# Finding perpendicular distances with triangles

Tags: trigonometry

Since I made this problem I have been trying to solve it, I know is completely defined because I use CAD software to check it, so it is doable, The problem is to find $2y$, $x_1$, and $x_2$ in terms of $a$, $b$, $c$, and $\theta$ in the diagram below:

[image: diagram]

This is what I have advanced so far:

[image: diagram_with_calculations]

Then if we have the relation of $a, b, c, \theta,$ and $z$, we should be able to calculate $z$ if we are given numerical values for $a$, $b$, $c$, and $\theta$ later on, so now the last part would be to find $x_1$ and $x_2$ which are perpendicular to the yellow line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost done actually. Now that you know $y$,

$x_1 = (\sqrt{a^2-y^2 \cos^2\theta} - y \sin \theta) \cos \theta$

$x_2 = (\sqrt{b^2-y^2 \cos^2\theta} - y \sin \theta) \cos \theta$

As the blue line makes angle $(90^0 - \theta)$ with the yellow line on one of the sides $(90^0 + \theta$, on the other side).  So the blue line will make angle $\theta$ to the line segments $x_1$ and $x_2$.

Comment: thx, sometimes when you have too much time trying to solve the same problem you stop to look at the obvious things

Comment: sounds quite familiar :)